# How to include comment blocks starting with `//`

Tags: doxygen

I am trying to document a C library with Doxygen. It does not use the special comment block indicators listed [here](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#cppblock), but instead just `//`-style comments:

```
//
// ... text ...
//
```

How can I make doxygen recognise/include these?

Comment: [`doxygen`](https://doxygen.nl/) is open source, so you could improve it, but it probably is easier/faster to change the source code of your C library (e.g. using [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)... or [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/)... or your [Python](https://python.org/) script). Consider also [literate programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming) tools

Comment: You could write a filter that does the job for you (i.e. change the `//` to `///`) and set the appropriate setting in `FILTER_PATTERNS` though I **advise, with emphasis, against** it as it looks a good solution but might also have as consequence that some comments that are not intended to land in the documentation can land in the documentation as well.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch the hack that you propose is not a good idea (and will not land in the main version of doxygen, better said I think it will never land in the main version of doxygen)

Comment: Yes, I commented that `sed` is easier

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I agree that changing `//` to `///` might be the most elegant solution, but upstream will most probably not accept this change, so I need an alternative.

Comment: The remark "will most probably not accept this change" means that you have to convince upstream that documentation (generation) is essential. Most of the times a refusal of such a change is based on old patterns of upstream.

Comment: Upstream has stated rather clealy that they do not want to be bothered with changes required for a specific documentation builder. They regard generated documentation as a community task of little to no importance as people can look at the docstrings in the source code directly. I think there's no realistic chance to convince them.

Comment: With such an attitude regarding documentation I would drop the upstream project.

Comment: How large is the library (thousands of lines, or millions of them)? And what is that library supposed to do (word processing, or driving a neurosurgery robot)? What will happen to you if (because of lack of documentation) your software project fails?